# urldecode() function not decoding whitespace +

Tags: php, urlencode, urldecode

I am working on a form to submit a file for deletion. As many of these filenames have whitespace elements I have used the urlencode() function. However, when I urldecode() the + symbol is not decoded to whitespace & an error occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code from delete.php with some variations on decoding:

```
<?php 

$file= 'test image.jpg';

echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"deleteFile\" action=\"delete.php?delete=true\">          
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"FileToDelete\" value=".urlencode($file)." >
<input class=\"delete_button\" type=\"submit\" value=\"X\"></div></form>";

if(isset($_GET['delete']) && $_GET['delete']=='true') {   
echo $_POST[urldecode("FileToDelete")].' #1'.'<br>';
echo $_POST[urldecode('FileToDelete')].' #2'.'<br>';
echo $_POST[htmlspecialchars(urldecode('FileToDelete'))].' #3'.'<br>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not decoding the filename, but the text `FileToDelete`. My guess is you want to do the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && $_GET['delete']=='true') {   
    $decodedFilename = urldecode($_POST['FileToDelete']);

    echo $decodedFilename.' #1'.'<br>';
    echo $decodedFilename.' #2'.'<br>';
    echo htmlspecialchars($decodedFilename).' #3'.'<br>';
}
```